# Mixin nested in paragraph

Tags: pug

I am currently trying to bring a figure into a block of text, however I run into the following issue:

```
mixin figure
  figure(style="float:right" width="50%")
    img(src="image.jpeg" alt="Alttext")
    figcaption Caption

block content
  div(class="content-width")
    h1 Heading
    p.
      #[+figure]
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

evaluates to

```
<div class="content-width">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p></p>
<figure>[...]</figure>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

I would have expected to get the following result:

```
<div class="content-width">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>
<figure>[...]</figure>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
</p>
```

Is this behavior correct and I'm using Pug wrong? Or have I stumbled into a bug?

Comment: If you paste your code to one of the editable textarea fields at [pugjs.org](https://pugjs.org/), you should get the expected (correct) result. Or at least I'm getting the expected result. What version of Pug are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Figure elements are block-level elements, and are not permitted to be children of paragraph elements in HTML. The output you're seeing is likely the browser trying to correct the invalid HTML by closing the unclosed paragraph tag as soon as it encounters the figure element.

---

**Previous Answer:**

The `#[]` syntax is strictly for [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation), not for mixins.

Instead, use the [dot block](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) syntax *after* the mixin, like this—

```
block content
  div(class="content-width")
    h1 Heading
    p
      +figure
      .
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

—or use the [piped text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text) syntax, like this:

```
block content
  div(class="content-width")
    h1 Heading
    p
      +figure
      | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

Comment: Your recommendation does not seem to work, the issue still persists. I made a repository so one can reproduce the issue. https://github.com/Paktosan/expresspugtest

Comment: @Paktosan ah, I should have taken a closer look at the elements you were using. I've revised my answer.

Comment: So I just wrote malformed HTML, how embarassing. :) Thanks for the help!